# Dell Inspiron 14R - Is there a Switchable Graphics utility?

Tags: graphics-card, dell-inspiron, fps

I just bought an Inspiron 14R (N4110) for my brother who loves to play Minecraft. I made sure to get the discrete ATI card. Now, in the ATI CCC program, I placed Minecraft and Java on the list of application to be run in High Performance mode (on the ATI card), but the FPS in minecraft looks to be about the same (18-23 fps). My other brother has the previous iteration of the same laptop with somewhat similar specs and he is getting 48-56 FPS. I am concerned that the graphics are not switching over properly. Does anyone know of a utility that I can use to monitor which applications are using which cards?

Comment: Are you sure your Dell has switchable graphics? Its the ati 6470m correct? Could you check in your device manager under video cards that list intel hd 3000 and ati 6470m?

Answer (score 1):

According to the dell promo page for Inspiron 14r there is some form of switchable graphics which depends on whether your laptop is in AC or battery mode. So make sure you're connected to the power outlet before playing games.
And if you're still skeptical about it click this [link](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&objectID=c02731962&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN&aoid=35252) and follow the steps to make sure this feature is available.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have the same notebook model, but the switchable radeon gpu, too.
Lenovo has a little utilty in the power manager to switch to a certain gpu instead of automatic choosing.
Maybe you find something similiar in your Dell settings?